# How to enable java HotSpot VM compiler

Tags: java, tomcat, jvm, jit

I am using java 1.8.0_05, Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
I am running a java web app on tomcat 8.0.43

I recently deployed my `.war` file by dropping it in the webapps folder.

This resulted in the following message being logged:

> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: CodeCache is full. Compiler
>   has been disabled. Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Try
>   increasing the code cache size using -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
>   CodeCache: size=245760Kb used=244058Kb max_used=244079Kb free=1701Kb 
>   bounds [...] 
>   total_blobs=48344 nmethods=47669 adapters=584  compilation: disabled
>   (not enough contiguous free space left)

How can I check what the current status of the compiler is now, to see if it's still disabled?

How can I enable the compiler? Can I simply restart tomcat?

There doesn't seem to be any noticeable different in how my application is running (eg: in terms of speed).

Interestingly, I didn't get this message when deploying the same application to an identical server. This is why I would like to first just turn the compiler back on rather than changing settings (eg: ReservedCodeCacheSize) as the message recommends.

Then, if the problem persists I can see which settings I need to change.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the part where you explained that you already deployed this on an identical server. Are you sure they are identical? Did you take a look at the Code Cache Size? Maybe it would be a good idea to monitor with VisualVM both servers.

Also, have into account that the use of the application will cause the Cache to load up. Maybe the other server doesn't have the same load?

Comment: Thanks! Do you have a good resource for how to run VisualVM if the app is running on a linux server? Will I have to run it remotely?

Comment: Yes. I've edited my answer with some more detail.

Comment: Update 5 is very old (4.5 years). I would try update 181.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you think that’s what’s causing the issue? Could it be something with my code that I’m doing incorrectly? Because from what I understand typical application don’t run into this issue, and my app is not unusually large...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Addressing your individual questions + 1 recommendation:

- **How to check if the JIT compiler is still disabled?**

The easiest thing to do is to **start up a jvisualvm (already shipped with JDK), then check the used codecache space**. If your CodeCache is full, the JIT compiler will remain disabled. to check the Code Cache memory space:

1. install the MBeans JVisualVM plugin.
2. go to Mbeans
3. open java.lang/MemoryPool/Code Cache
4. check variable "Usage" (double-click)

This will give you an overview of where you are.

- **How can I enable the compiler? Can I simply restart tomcat?**

**Yes, a restart will certainly reset the state of the cache.** The only other way to restart your compiler would be if you have already started the JVM with the right parameters. (enabling `UseCodeCacheFlushing`)

- **No difference in how my application is running?**

JIT optimizes your code, **but depending on your application and the way you use it, you might not see any noticable difference**. Assuming you run a webapp (because of Tomcat), the network transmission speed or your browser rendering pages are likely orders of magnitude slower than what JIT gains you in terms of core Java speed.

- **"I didn't get this message when deploying the same application"**

**JIT compiling is dependent on the code that is being executed at that moment.** The same application might run quite differently under the hood on the level where JIT works. When it comes to low-level functions, the more 3rd party libraries you use, the less you can be sure about what is happening on all those threads you have no control over of.

- the suggestion:

**Please upgrade that Java version. It is very rare (u_05) to be on such an early JDK8 version, and quite dangerous.** Java8 was not the most stable release when it came out, and had easily reproducible bugs even at later releases. [There have been over 1000 bugs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_8_updates) fixed in JDK8. Many of these were directly addressing JIT issues. If you have any control over the environment you are talking to, upgrade it. If you do not, notify the responsible person.

Comment: Thanks! 1)I looked into monitoring but abandoned because it seemed involved. I am running on linux. Do you recommend running MBeans remotely then? Or is there a way to run it on the server? 2) At the time the message was logged, I had 3 versions of my app deployed (see Tomcat autoDeploy), they undeploy within an hour). Could this have caused the issue? 3) Is there something unique in my code that is causing the issue (eg: too many methods, too many public static variable, etc.)? 4) The upgrade is a good idea and possible. I will look into it!

Comment: Correction, the configuration I was referring to in (2) above is called ["parallel deployment"](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html#Parallel_deployment) (not autoDeploy).

Comment: 1. You can remotely connect to a JVM if you enable JMX. Normally it easy, except some network gotchas. if you are lucky, it takes 2 min and you are all set. If not, just post an SO question and flag me. 2. Don't really get this whole concept, sorry. 3. I cannot think of any "special code" that could cause excessive amount of JIT compiling. 4. If update is an option, certainly take it, and see your situation afterwards. I am almost sure that the landscape will change.

Comment: @GergelyBacso Why is the JIT compiler completely disabled when the code cache is full? Why doesn't it at least keep using the compiled methods present in the cache when it became full?

Comment: @ArjunBhattacharya, the fact that the JIT compiler is disabled does not mean that the already compiled code is not being used still. It just means that no more code will be compiled at this point.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue a while ago and this is what I cant tell you:

Once the Code Cache becomes full the compiler is automatically disabled.

**Will it be automatically restarted?**

No. And it will stay down until the JVM is restarted.

> Can I simply restart tomcat?

Yes. But it will probably happen again.

> There doesn't seem to be any noticeable different in how my application is running (eg: in terms of speed).

In the long run there will be some issues since code that could be cached and optimized can no longer be compiled and stored there.

**What can you do?**

1. You could increase a bit -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize
2. You could enable -XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing. The drawback is that if your CodeCache size is way too low, and you constantly hit the flushing threshold, the performance will be affected since you are spending CPU resources in the flushing process.

I would increase a bit the CodeCacheSize, enable the flush, and monitor the App with VisualVM or something that lets you look at the current state of the CodeCache. Monitoring will help you understand if you are reaching the thresholds once in a while or if it happens a lot.

Remember that CodeCache is separated from the Heap, so looking at HeapSize won't help you.

**Edit:**
Regarding VisualVM, here are the official steps to connect to a remote JVM:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/applications_remote.html

Just make sure JMX is enabled and it should work right away.

Regarding the issue with many apps running at the same time... Well yeah, technically Standard Tomcat starts one JVM for all the apps. Cache Space will be shared.

You could also monitor this case by Attaching VisualVM to the JVM, undeploying an app and checking if the space has been freed.

You could also consider using an Enterprise container which will let you create one JVM per App.

Comment: Thanks! (1)When the message was logged I had 3 versions of my application deployed (see tomcat autoDeploy. Basically, I deploy new versions and tomcat undeploys old ones within an hour). Could this have had an effect on the CodeCache size (ie: 3 times the load because 3 apps were deployed)? (2) I don't consider my webapp to be unique. And as I understand, this issue shouldn't arise under normal circumstances. So is there something that I did that caused this (eg: many methods, many public static variables, etc.)?

Comment: Correction: the configuration I was referring to in (1) above is called ["parallel deployment"](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html#Parallel_deployment) (not autoDeploy)

Comment: Yes. Tomcat by default starts a single JVM and Code Cache space is shared.

Comment: @Diego you say that "In the long run there will be some issues...". I am currently facing this! Now, when the code cache is full and subsequently the JIT compiler is disabled, I would expect an immediate performance degradation since the cache and JIT compiler is not being used at all. FYI my app is showing a gradual (2-3 days after cache full) slowdown as well. Where is my understanding wrong?